# Have the WebView still play the video while in background

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I wish to play my video, coming from youtube, in the background. To stream any youtube video, I simply do:

```
         webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.test);
        WebSettings settings = webView.Settings;
        settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.LoadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/jjaXCxKudIo"); // after embed las part of link after = sign
```

However, putting the activity to the background stops the video. Once returned, the video will start over.

This is not how I want this. I want the video to keep playing, but invisible (yet still audible).

I tried pushing the webview into a service, but this didnt work either.
I tried putting the webview into a notification in the android notificatio bar, but I wasnt able to initialize the webview like so:

```
       RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(PackageName, Resource.Layout.Notificaion);



      WebView webView = contentView.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.test);
      WebSettings settings = webView.Settings;
      settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
      webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
      webView.LoadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/jjaXCxKudIo"); // after embed las part of link after = sign
```

This didnt work, because contentview has no property for "findviewbyid"

Does anyone maybe know how to achieve that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the system before android 8.0, you could define a custom webview, then override the OnWindowVisibilityChanged() method like following code.

```
class MediaWebView : WebView
{
    public MediaWebView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnWindowVisibilityChanged([GeneratedEnum] ViewStates visibility)
    {
       // base.OnWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
       if (visibility !=ViewStates.Gone) base.OnWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    }


}
```

Android 8.0 or Android 8.0 later, it cannot be achieved.

Comment: Hi and thanks. This is what I did now but unfortunately, I would need it for Oreo 8.0 plus. Ive decided to abondon the project but thanks a lot :) this answer is correct.